# How to tell Scala that a def returns TypeRef[this.type]

Tags: scala, types

I have a set of objects like the following:

```
abstract class RecordType[T <: Record]
object RecordType1 extends RecordType[Record1]
object RecordType2 extends RecordType[Record2]
...
```

I'd like to use them in the following way, i.e. each `RecordX` has a `def recordType: RecordType[RecordX]`, but I have not been able to figure out the proper syntax (assuming that this is possible):

```
abstract class Record {
  def recordType: RecordType[this.type]
}
class Record1 extends Record {
  override def recordType: RecordType[Record1] = RecordType1
}
class Record2 extends Record {
  override def recordType: RecordType[Record2] = RecordType2
}
...
```

This produces the error that the overriding methods have incompatible types.

I've tried the following as a starting point / compromise

```
abstract class Record {
  def recordType[T <: Record]: RecordType[T]
}
class Record1 extends Record {
  override def recordType: RecordType[Record1] = RecordType1
}
```

but this produces the error

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : RecordType1.type
[error]  required: RecordType[Record1]
```

Is there a way to accomplish the first goal of requiring that each `Subclass` return `RecordType[Subclass]`, or barring that is there a way to fix the second set of code?

Comment: `this.type` doesn't mean what you think it means. It's the type with only one instance `this`, not `Record1` or other subtype of `Record`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is one of the standard approaches for this problem. Another is to use type members:

```
abstract class Record {
  type ThisType <: Record

  def recordType: RecordType[ThisType]
}

class Record1 {
  type ThisType = Record1

  override def recordType: RecordType[Record1] = RecordType1
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a cleaner solution than what I was doing

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have found a solution:

```
abstract class RecordType[T <: Record[T]]
object RecordType1 extends RecordType[Record1]

abstract class Record[T <: Record[T]] {
  def recordType: RecordType[T]
}
class Record1 extends Record[Record1] {
  override def recordType: RecordType[Record1] = RecordType1
}
```